# Spring @Transactional placement

Tags: spring, transactional

I'm recently playing a little with Spring/JPA2 to understand better how it works. During my experiments I found some strange behaviour. The question is:

**Why the following code works well (confirmed record added in db):**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void add(User user) {
        doAdd(user);
    }

    public void doAdd(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }
}
```

**But the following (@Transactional annotation moved to inner method):**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void add(User user) {
        doAdd(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doAdd(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }
}
```

**Throws exception:**

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:273)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy556.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.UserDAO.doAdd(UserDAO.java:24)
    ...
```

Comment: In both cases UserDao.add() method is called from @Service class.

Comment: Not strange at, works as expected. Spring AOP by default uses proxies, internal method calls don't pass through the proxy, hence your `@Transactional` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

[Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

The @Transactional annotation support works by wrapping the actual DAO instance in a Proxy, which intercepts the method calls and starts/commits the transaction. In the second example the actual UserDAO instance is calling the doSave method and therefore there is no Proxy to intercept the method call.